# Drupal - Redirect just the homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

due to internal politics with a project I need to redirect only the homepage of a site built in drupal to a different url. I want to be able to access the rest of the site to show people but just that when it goes to the homepage it redirects you.

I want to create a copy of the homepage and then have the original homepage automatically redirect to the new url....meta refresh wouldnt work because there is lag time...

Anyone know how to do this with .htaccess ?

Thanks

Add new comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding this rule as **first rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /new-home-page [L,R]
```

Comment: Is ^$ the homepage or everypage?

Comment: `^$` means empty in regex and in the rewrite rules inside `.htaccess` it matches ONLY the home page.

Comment: I added that to the drupal htaccess file but it didn't do anything.  do need it in a specific area of the existing file?

Comment: Yes this need to be **very first rule** in your main .htaccess. And then access your website as `http://domain.com/`

Comment: worked perfectly for the drupal site, I am now also trying the same thing for a site built in expression engine, its the only thing in the htaccess file but its not doing anything

Comment: Great to know it worked for Drupal. I request you to accept this answer and create a new one for the expression engine problem with all the relevant details to get better answer.